# Missing KCPRNMON.DLL

Tags: drivers, printer

I'm trying to install a printer on my Windows 7 machine (both with and without SP1 installed) and during installation I get an error that it can't find KCPRNMON.DLL - any ideas?

The printer is a UTAX CD1230 KX, and I'm using their driver. I've used the exact same driver without any problems on other Windows 7 machines.

Comment: the KC prefix indicates that this is not a standard windows library. maybe check your documentation?

Answer (score 1):

[That DLL is a Kyocera one](http://173.45.246.152/info/kcprnmon.html). I find it odd that the UTAX driver/installer would need it, unless maybe the UTAX is a rebranded Kyocera (as the KX in the model name seems to suggest).

Perhaps you could try installing some Kyocera drivers to see if the DLL gets added, or try copying it (and any other associated files) from the other PCs that were able to install the driver?